# my 2003 Santa Fe won't turn over but has full power

Tags: starting, hyundai, santa-fe

My 2003 Santa Fe wont start. I turn the key and I have power but no starter engaging. They looked at my car two days later and the car started. They said it was probably a broken wire they found on the ignition harness.

Two days later the exact thing happened again. Hyundai said guarantee its the ground wire to the chassis. I told the mechanics this, but it sat for a week (they were busy ... not knocking them, they were busy). Anyway, they finally got it in to check. What I was told and before they even looked they tried the key and it worked!! They did check the ground cable and it was all corroded. Drove it home yesterday went to start it ... same problem again!!!

Answer (score 2):

The starter solenoid contacts are probably badly worn which causes the intermittent starting.  You should be able to hear the solenoid clicking each time you turn the key.  Occasionally a good contact will be made on the solenoid contacts and the starter will turn.  If you are confident, you could use an old screwdriver across the large connections on the solenoid (if they are both visible) to bypass the solenoid to see if the starter then turns.  Make sure the car is out of gear and the ignition is off.

Comment: I've used an open end wrench (spanner) to great effect jumping the terminals at the back of the solenoid. What you've suggested is about the easiest way to test it while on the vehicle ... just be careful you don't ground the other end ;-)